# Update php variable in head while writing in footer

Tags: php, html, css, variables

When I'm composing my page, I keep updating the variable `$links`. This refers to css links that will be placed in the `<head>` section of the html page.

But when I'm at the bottom of the page, and I've got my final value for `$links`, I want it to be written in the `<head>` instead of at the end of the page.

I tried it with `str_replace`, but that just writes it down at the bottom..

The php looks like this:

```
<head>
    <?php echo $links; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include 'gallery.php';
        $links .= <link type="text/css" href="/css/lightbox.css">;
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to populate your $links variable before the head tag if. Just move the processing to the top.

Comment: Separate your logic from your output. You can't change the value _after_ you've output it (i.e. with `echo`) as it's already been calculated and sent to the browser.

Comment: Indeed, the answer is simple: decide on which links you want to use before you output them. That means you will need to move a bunch of your code above your `<head>` statement. In fact, it's always a good idea to do that anyway. Don't have any "decision making" code within your HTML.

Comment: No. You don't need to go to the bottom of the page to get your link list. Calculate necessary things on top of the page. Store them in variables, arrays. And then start to output the HTML. First your links, later your HTML structure, using the stored values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comment about separating logic from the view, in the ideal case by the time you write the page, you have all the information already assembled...

However, as a quick fix that does not involve too much refactoring, you can use output buffering:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<head>
    PLACEHOLDER_LINKS
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include 'gallery.php';
        $links .= <link type="text/css" href="/css/lightbox.css">;
    ?>
</body>
<?php 
$html = ob_get_clean();
$html = str_replace( "PLACEHOLDER_LINKS", $links, $html);
echo $html;
```

I do suggest however looking into the MVC pattern and frameworks that implement it... it can save a lot of headaches like this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way but just for your information. You can also include a css file using javascript.

JS

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/xyz.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Which in your case can be done by writting this script in the footer section.